# Apache Thrift: Returning a list/container

Tags: list, thrift

I made a simple thrift file like this:

**thrifttest.thrift**

```
namespace cpp thrifttest
namespace d thrifttest
namespace java thrifttest
namespace php thrifttest
namespace perl thrifttest

service Test {

    list<i64> ping();

}
```

and in shell ran "thrift --gen cpp thrifttest.thrift"

However, when I looked at gen-cpp/Test_server.skeleton.cpp it made the i64 list a parameter, not a return type:

**Test_server.skeleton.cpp (excerpt)**

```
void ping(std::vector<int64_t> & _return) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("ping\n");
}
```

and in my server.cpp program, after I make a function ping() that returns an "std::vector &", the compiler complains that

> error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘TestHandler’
>   server.cpp:30:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘TestHandler’:

this is the full code for server.cpp
**server.cpp**

```
#include <thrift/concurrency/ThreadManager.h>
#include <thrift/concurrency/PosixThreadFactory.h>
#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <thrift/server/TSimpleServer.h>
#include <thrift/server/TThreadPoolServer.h>
#include <thrift/server/TThreadedServer.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TTransportUtils.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

#include "gen-cpp/Test.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;
using namespace apache::thrift::server;

using boost::shared_ptr;

using namespace thrifttest;

using namespace boost;

unsigned long giant[100];

class TestHandler : virtual public TestIf {
 public:
  TestHandler() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          giant[i] = -1;
      }
  }


  std::vector<int64_t> & ping() {
        return (std::vector<int64_t> &)giant;
    }

  void ping(std::vector<int64_t> & bla) {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  shared_ptr<TestHandler> handler(new TestHandler());
  shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new TestProcessor(handler));
  shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
  shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
  shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

  TSimpleServer server(processor,
                       serverTransport,
                       transportFactory,
                       protocolFactory);

  printf("Starting the server...\n");
  server.serve();
  printf("done.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I accidentally came across an article ([StackOverflow: Handling Apache Thrift List Map Return Types in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828772/handling-apache-thrift-list-map-return-types-in-c)) that discussed this exact issue (though the answer didn't work in my case). Turns out, thrift uses a pass-by-reference syntax, even though ["Thrift uses a pass by value model" - Gupta](http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/). So here's an example:

**.thrift file**

```
service Test {

    list<string> ping();
}
```

**Server side**

```
void ping(std::vector<string> & _return) {
    _return.push_back("hello");    //initialize the vector _return with values "hello","world"
    _return.push_back("world");
}
```

**Client side**

```
std::vector<string> result;     //create vector "result" for storing the values
client.ping(result);
printf("%s %s!\n", result[0].c_str(), result[1].c_str());   //c_str() turns the vector string into a C-style string
```

**Client output (after starting server)**

> hello world!

and thank you Thrift for the lack of documentation, I had a blast!  #4hoursgoogling&crying

Comment: +1 for `and thank you Thrift for the lack of documentation, I had a blast! #4hoursgoogling&crying`.

In the same phase curently. :'(

Comment: if you need anything, I can try to help :)

Comment: First, open source lives also from you. It's both ways. Crying will not make it any better, nor help anyone having the same questions. Next, there *is* documentation available (and yes, it is far from being perfect) like tutorials and other sample code, like books and whitepapers and blog posts, all of which are linked from other SO questions multiple times. And last not least, you can ask at any time here on SO, in the Thrift mailing list and the #thrift Freenode channel. Maybe that's not enough and you know better? Great, you are more than welcome, we accept patches and contributions!

Comment: thanks for all the resources! I haven't used thrift in a while, but I'm sure these will come in handy to others

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your question, there are a few drawbacks with returning a container class directly.

Instead, I would wrap the container into a `struct` and return that one. This way you can add any fields later without the need for a new service method. Furthermore, the container itself can be omitted if that becomes necessary - you can't return a `NULL` container for technical reasons with Thrift.